# How to use calibration parameters from KITTI?

Tags: matlab, camera-calibration

I'm working on stereo vision and I am using data from The KITTI Vision Benchmark Suite, The calibration parameters they use are very different from the parameters that the stereo camera calibrator toolbox produce and I couldn't find a way to use their data in MATLAB.

I also tried to use their calibration images in stereo camera calibrator toolbox which looks like this:
[Calibration Toolbox MATLAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxZ5N.png)

But when I run the calibration it fails saying
[Calibration fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEVC0.png):

> unable to estimate camera parameters. images may contain severe less
>   distortion or the 3-D orientations of the calibration pattern are too
>   similar across images, if calibration pattern orientations are too
>   similar, try removing very similar images or adding additional images
>   with pattern in invalid orientations

Please help me if you have any idea on how to solve this

Comment: Can you please include the error messages as text in your question?

Comment: unable to estimate camera parameters. images may contain severe less distortion or the 3-D orientations of the calibration pattern are too similar across images, if calibration pattern orientations are too similar, try removing very similar images or adding additional images with pattern in invalid orientations

Comment: I am also having the same problem. @ajshort: All the images have multiple checkerboards in different orientations.